# Has anyone who took part in the App Showdown gotten the promised t-shirt?

Tags: application-development

The title says all. On the contest site http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/ there's statement **"Every submitted app also gets an Ubuntu T-Shirt!"**. I haven't received anything so far.

----------------EDIT-------------

Just received Ubuntu t-shirt! Thanks @David Planella!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I apologize for the delay, but we've finally got some good news. Due to the overwhelming success in terms of participants, it's taken a while to get all of the T-shirts and organize the logistics with shipments.

A batch of T-shirts has bent sent out today and they're going to get to everyone soon. It's unlikely that everyone will get their T-shirts before Christmas, but some of the participants located closer to the UK might :)